# Unable to host WordPress website on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, phpmyadmin

I am trying to host a WordPress website on azure.
I have successfully uploaded the files and database in phpMyAdmin.

I checked which user is accessing my database its shows as azure.

When I try to open the link (https://websitename.azurewebsites.net/) where its is hosted on azure ,it gives the following error:

1. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
   access permissions. Error establishing a database connection

Can someone tell me where can I find the right user name and password to connect to phpMyAdmin in azure

I tried using the FTP details, I connected in FTP but giving an error when try opening the website using link mentioned above.

Comment: Where's your database and how are you connecting to it?

Comment: I got the solution for this, you need to connect to the localdb that's created when you install WordPress.This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just click the App Services menu and you add a new one, you can filter for WordPress and there are a lot of preinstalled instances, you can just start to use it. It is already configured for your.

[image]

Comment: I got the solution for this After you install Wordpress you need to upload your database in the localdb that's created.